# pprint jinja2 debug variable helper

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2

I'm trying to use http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#pprint `pprint` function like this:

`{{ pprint(player) }}` in my html file, but I get the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
UndefinedError: 'pprint' is undefined
```

Jinja2 is a template engine for python.
Anyone could help me to display variables for easy debug?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to use it this way:

```
{{ flash_messages|pprint }}
```

or in your case:

```
{{ player|pprint}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this output: `<TWIIT.Entities.Entity.Village instance at 0x0000000005E705C8> <TWIIT.Entities.Entity.Village instance at 0x00000000050CDDC8> <TWIIT.Entities.Entity.Village instance at 0x00000000050E5648> <TWIIT.Entities.Entity.Village instance at 0x00000000050E5388> <TWIIT.Entities.Entity.Village instance at 0x0000000004E286C8>`, how can I get a readable format? I thought this function was about helping me ^^'

Comment: This is like pprint in python. However you can implement your own filter or override __repr__ method of your Village class to return some useful info.

Comment: @Vadorequest you probably want to use `{{ player.__dict__ }}` as well is a good idea to have the `dir()` function available, but for that you would have to extend the jinja environment